# Bootstrap modal is transparent

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I used what I've saw on a tutorial but it seems having a problem on my part coz i read other post on google but no one help on my problem.
how can i make my modal dialog not transparent?

here what it looks like
http://i57.tinypic.com/20pr18w.png

here's my codes

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <h3>Picture</h3>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#basicModal">Upload a photo</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal-backdrop modal fade" id="basicModal" style="display: none;" data-backdrop="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Update Display Picture</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body col-xs-12">
       <div class="col-xs-4">
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-success text-center" style=" margin-top:50%;width:150px; height:50px;"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Upload a photo</a>
        </div>

       <div class="col-xs-8">
       <h4 class="pull-right">PREVIEW</h4>
         <div class="center-block" style="background-image:url(img/default-picture.jpg);
            width: 200px;
             height: 200px;
             background-size: cover;
             display: block;
             border-radius: 100px;
             -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
             -moz-border-radius: 100px;">
         </div>
       </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Overwrite the default opacity of that modal:

```
.modal-backdrop, 
.modal-backdrop.fade.in{
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100);
background: #fff;
}
```

If the above is not working then try with `!important` keyword:

```
.modal-backdrop, 
.modal-backdrop.fade.in{
opacity: 1 !important;
filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same issue,
I have added :
`style="background: #fff"` in `<div class="modal-content">`
finally it looks like..
`<div class="modal-content" style="background: #fff">`

And it seems working like a charm!
Cheers.